# Reading 4 column file with two columns entry matched in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am recording the mobile node's coordinates in text file through source code file. I want to read this text file from tcl script to access most recently recorded coordinates for a particular node. Following is the code i have tried yet but it is not returning anything.

```
proc accessLoc { attime node_id} {
    set fb [open "node_info.txt" r]
    set filecontent [read $fb]
    set input_list [split $filecontent "\n"]
    set data [lsearch -all -inline $input_list "$node_id"]
    foreach elem $data {
        if {[lindex $elem 0] eq {attime} && {[lindex [split $elem " "]1] eq {node_id}} {
            set xCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]2]
            set yCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]3]
            return [list xCoord yCoord]
        }
        close $fb
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please add sample content from node_info.txt

Comment: @Sharad I have shared it below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you've got a minor error in that you've put the `close` in the wrong place. Since the data is relatively small and allows you to use `read`, you can and *should* `close` immediately afterwards so that the file descriptor isn't leaked. Let's fix that now.

```
proc accessLoc { attime node_id} {
    set fb [open "node_info.txt" r]
    set filecontent [read $fb]
    close $fb

    set input_list [split $filecontent "\n"]
    set data [lsearch -all -inline $input_list "$node_id"]
    foreach elem $data {
        if {[lindex $elem 0] eq {attime} && {[lindex [split $elem " "]1] eq {node_id}} {
            set xCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]2]
            set yCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]3]
            return [list xCoord yCoord]
        }
    }  
}
```

Next, let's make a failure to find what you want an error rather than having it return nothing. That'll give you a definite indication of a failure, which is much less bewildering. (You can `catch` an `error` within a wider context, or use `try` from Tcl 8.6 onwards for more subtlety.)

```
proc accessLoc { attime node_id} {
    set fb [open "node_info.txt" r]
    set filecontent [read $fb]
    close $fb
    set input_list [split $filecontent "\n"]
    set data [lsearch -all -inline $input_list "$node_id"]
    foreach elem $data {
        if {[lindex $elem 0] eq {attime} && {[lindex [split $elem " "]1] eq {node_id}} {
            set xCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]2]
            set yCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]3]
            return [list xCoord yCoord]
        }
    }
    error "did not find the item"
}
```

You also probably don't need the `lsearch`; a scan of the data isn't *that* expensive. That lets me shorten the code a little further:

```
proc accessLoc { attime node_id} {
    set fb [open "node_info.txt" r]
    set filecontent [read $fb]
    close $fb
    foreach elem [split $filecontent "\n"] {
        if {[lindex $elem 0] eq {attime} && {[lindex [split $elem " "]1] eq {node_id}} {
            set xCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]2]
            set yCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]3]
            return [list xCoord yCoord]
        }
    }
    error "did not find the item"
}
```

But that's not what the *real* problem is. You've got problems on these lines, which really do not look like what I'd expect as they are referring to literals and using unusual forms of `lindex` (no space between the list and the index? Unlikely to do what you expect!):

```
        if {[lindex $elem 0] eq {attime} && {[lindex [split $elem " "]1] eq {node_id}} {
            set xCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]2]
            set yCoord [lindex [split $elem " "]3]
            return [list xCoord yCoord]
```

Instead, I'd expect something more like this:

```
        lassign [split $elem " "] thisAtTime thisId xCoord yCoord
        if {$thisAtTime eq $attime && $thisId eq $node_id} {
            return [list $xCoord $yCoord]
```

We can split the whole line at once with `split`, and breaking it up into fields (err, local variables) with names is very convenient, and `lassign` is designed for the purpose. Then, we can simplify the comparison expression (remembering that variables should be prefixed with `$` when read) and the following `return` also benefits. Let's put it all in context.

```
proc accessLoc { attime node_id} {
    set fb [open "node_info.txt" r]
    set filecontent [read $fb]
    close $fb
    foreach elem [split $filecontent "\n"] {
        lassign [split $elem " "] thisAtTime thisId xCoord yCoord
        if {$thisAtTime eq $attime && $thisId eq $node_id} {
            return [list $xCoord $yCoord]
        }
    }
    error "did not find the item"
}
```

Comment: @Fellows thanks for your detailed answer. I have tried this solution but facing an error "invalid command name 'lassign' . however, I have found on web that this might be a problem with old tcl version. I am running 8.6 tcl version but still getting this error. Can you please suggest what could be the problem as I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe a bad installation? Can you tell us what `puts $tcl_pathlevel` prints? Meanwhile, a quick fix is to replace the invocation of `lassign` with the old idiom: `foreach {thisAtTime thisId xCoord yCoord} [split $elem " "] break`

Comment: @Peter its prints "can't read "tcl_pathlevel" : no such variable". Did you mean 'puts $tcl_patchLevel' ? if so, then it prints '8.6.5'.  It is throwing error "did not find the item" ,although, there is such an entry present in the file. I am waiting for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @Mary: yes, sorry, it was `tcl_patchlevel` I meant. Ok, I have no idea at all why `lassign` doesn't work. At least I have confirmed that the procedure works with the `foreach` invocation I suggested; at least if `$filecontent` in the outer `foreach` is changed to `[string trim $filecontent]`. If it doesn't work for you, you might have to take the long way around and verify that the values assigned to `elem`, `thisAtTime` etc get the values they should get. If you post a few lines from your data file, I could try it here.

Comment: @Peter: yes sure. Following are few lines from my 'node_info.txt' file.
 I want to get most recent x and y coordinates of a specific node which would be (obviously) at the end of file. It should ignore all the above entries of that specific node. It should match time and node then return x and y coordinates of that node.

Comment: 71.658185 7 105.2988 50.0000 

71.668167 0 300.0000 150.0000 

71.678665 7 105.3404 50.0000 

71.688627 0 300.0000 150.0000 

71.699145 7 105.3817 50.0000 
71.709067 0 300.0000 150.0000 
71.719625 7 105.4227 50.0000 
71.729787 0 300.0000 150.0000 
71.740105 7 105.4633 50.0000 
71.749987 0 300.0000 150.0000 
71.760585 7 105.5042 50.0000 
71.770347 0 300.0000 150.0000 
71.781065 7 105.5453 50.0000 
71.790787 0 300.0000 150.0000

Comment: @Donal and Peter Thank you guys. Finally it works. The problem was in data file. if statement was comparing exact float values (number of digits after decimal point) of 'attime'. So, I converted this decimal to integer before passing to accessLoc procedure then it worked. Thank you again for your time and suggestions. May Almighty reward you for this.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

(This is not really an answer, more a comment on Donal Fellows' answer, posted as an answer for the sake of readability.)

If you can't use `lassign` and you want to get the last match of potentially several, you should do something like this:

```
proc accessLoc {attime node_id} {
    set result NONE
    # due to Donal Fellows
    set fb [open "node_info.txt" r]
    set filecontent [read $fb]
    close $fb
    foreach elem [split [string trim $filecontent] "\n"] {
        # Leave exactly one of the two following lines uncommented
        # lassign [split $elem " "] thisAtTime thisId xCoord yCoord
        foreach {thisAtTime thisId xCoord yCoord} [split $elem " "] break
        if {$thisAtTime eq $attime && $thisId eq $node_id} {
            set result [list $xCoord $yCoord]
        }
    }
    if {$result eq "NONE"} {
        error "did not find the item"
    } else {
        return $result
    }
}
```

To get the last match, it saves each match in the variable `result`, which means that at the end of the scan the value of the variable is the last match.

I can't make this code fail to find a line in the given data file. Example:

```
% accessLoc 71.729787 0
300.0000 150.0000
```

So, it's still a mystery why you get errors.